# FileInfo in DataTable not working

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have two `comboBoxes`. In first I select Brand, in the second I select the model. I want also to display a `picture` according to model choice. Everything seemed to work until I added that `FileInfo` column. Now the code is not working (I cant even choose the brand and model - `comboboxes are empty`). What is wrong:

```
        dtCategories = new DataTable();
        dtCategories.Columns.Add("CategoryID", typeof(int));
        dtCategories.Columns.Add("CategoryName", typeof(string));

        dtCategories.Rows.Add(0, "--Select--");
        dtCategories.Rows.Add(1, "Audi");
        dtCategories.Rows.Add(2, "BMW");
        dtCategories.Rows.Add(3, "Mercedes");

        dtItems = new DataTable();
        dtItems.Columns.Add("ItemID", typeof(int));
        dtItems.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
        dtItems.Columns.Add("CategoryID", typeof(int));
        dtItems.Columns.Add("Obrazek", typeof(FileInfo));

        dtItems.Rows.Add(2, "A1", 1, "a1.jpeg");
        dtItems.Rows.Add(3, "A3", 1, "a3.jpeg");
        dtItems.Rows.Add(4, "A4", 1, "a5.jpeg");
        dtItems.Rows.Add(5, "Seria 1", 2, "bmw1.jpeg");
        dtItems.Rows.Add(6, "Seria 2", 2, "bmw3.jpeg");
        dtItems.Rows.Add(7, "Seria 3", 2, "bmw5.jpeg");
        dtItems.Rows.Add(8, "C Klasa", 3, "C Klasa.jpeg");
        dtItems.Rows.Add(9, "E Klasa", 3, "E Klasa.jpeg");
        dtItems.Rows.Add(10, "S Klasa", 3, "S Klasa.jpeg");


        cbCategory.DisplayMember = "CategoryName";
        cbCategory.ValueMember = "CategoryID";
        cbCategory.DataSource = dtCategories;
```

And :

```
        private void cbCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        int categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(cbCategory.SelectedValue);
        if (categoryId > 0)
        {
            DataTable dtTemp = dtItems.Select(string.Format("CategoryID = {0}",  categoryId)).CopyToDataTable();

            DataRow drTemp = dtTemp.NewRow();
            drTemp["ItemID"] = 0;
            drTemp["ItemName"] = "--Select--";
            drTemp["CategoryID"] = 0;

            dtTemp.Rows.InsertAt(drTemp, 0);

            cbItems.DisplayMember = "ItemName";
            cbItems.ValueMember = "ItemID";
            cbItems.DataSource = dtTemp;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dtTemp.Columns[3].ToString());

        }
        else if (cbItems.DataSource != null)
        {
            cbItems.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think `"a1.jpeg"` isn't a valid FileInfo object. you should change column _Obrazek_ to **string**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileInfo` is not a valid data type for a column of a `DataTable`. See [DataColumn.DataType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx) for more information.

Do you receive an exception of some kind?

It might be your image paths are not correct.
You could try this code, which might be easier to debug:

```
var imagePath = dtTemp.Columns[3].ToString();
if (File.Exists(imagePath))
{
    var image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);
    pictureBox1.Image = image;
}
else
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException(); 
    // of course something more subtle is advisable
}
```

Comment: Ok, I changed 4 type to string type. But still what is wrong with :

        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(dtTemp.Columns[3].ToString());

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the data type of 4th column is `FileInfo`. Its that you aren't providing one when adding rows, instead a `string` type for the 4th column. Do

```
dtItems.Rows.Add(2, "A1", 1, new FileInfo("a1.jpeg"));
dtItems.Rows.Add(3, "A3", 1, new FileInfo("a3.jpeg"));
//etc..
```

That said, FileInfo is not a proper type usually for DataTable. For ur custom table it might work, but won't be compatible when loading from db directly to that datatable. But your datatable is fine as `DataSource`.

```
cbItems.DataSource = dtItems; //fine in your case.
```